# JSON Array with multiple parameters for POST request using Rest Assured

Tags: graphql, rest-assured, query-string, graphql-java

I am new to Rest Assured & GraphQL, Please can someone help me to create the body request from the following output:

```
{
"variables": {
    "EmployeeName": "ABC",
    "EmployeeDept": "Computers",
    "EmployeeStatus": false,
    "employeeRegion": [{
        "country": "USA",
        "values": ["NewYork"]
    }]
}
```

}

My sample:

```
ObjectNode variables = mapper.createObjectNode()
            .put("EmployeeName", EmployeeName)
            .put("EmployeeDept", "EmployeeDept")
            .put("EmployeeStatus", "EmployeeStatus")
```

Not sure how to construct the employeeRegion in variables?

Answer (score 0):

To make json array, just use List in java.
Example:

```
Region usa = new Region("USA", Arrays.asList("NewYork", "LA"));
Region uk = new Region("UK", Arrays.asList("London", "Manchester"));
List<Region> list = Arrays.asList(usa, uk);

....
put("employeeRegion", list);
```

Region.java

```
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

@Data
public class Region {
    private String country;
    private List<String> values;

    public Region(String country, List<String> values) {
        this.country = country;
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```